# $(this).attr("href") return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am trying to use bootbox with Twitter [Bootsrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

In the code below when I use `this.attr('href');` and I get `TypeError: this.attr is not a function`.

When I change to `$(this).attr('href');` i get `Undefined`.

```
 <a class="alert" href="list_users.php?id=123">Delete user</a>

 <script src="bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {

        if (result) {
            document.location.href = this.attr('href'); // doesn't work
            document.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); // Undefined
        }               
    });

    });
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: jQuery !== Javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not your jQuery event callback function anymore, but the bootbox callback... try [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to bind the context:

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", $.proxy(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            document.location.href = this.href;
        }
    }, this));
});
```

Comment: I guess `this.href` should do.

Comment: @PSL yeah the jQuery wrapper was kinda gratuitous

Comment: @Esailija - Do you know if this will be executed quicker or slower than just storing a variable that holds `this`?

Comment: @OptimusCrime slower, but this code is very cold so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Esailija - Good point. I've just always tried to avoid using `.proxy` because I feel like it is a little ugly hack.

Comment: I disagree in situations where you don't have an inline function the game is different and `.proxy` is far cleaner than currently known alternatives

Comment: @Esailija - Well, what if you need to use the variable that points to this from the callback? Using `.proxy`, that variable will be overwritten?

Comment: @OptimusCrime in my previous comment I didn't refer to a situation like this where you have inline function, but declared functions or methods of an object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this` or `$(this)` no longer is pointing to the link, but the `bootbox`-callback. This can fixed by storing the variable that `$(this)` is pointing to. Note that this is also considered good practice if you are using the same object multiple times.

```
$(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var obj = this;

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
        document.location.href = obj.href;
    }               
});
```